# Trouble creating thumbnails using Ordimage.ProcessCopy() within cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create thumbnails from blobs stored in a table in Oracle.  I can get the ordimage.processCopy to process individual rows, but I would like to run the process on all my rows in the table.

My understanding is that I need to create a cursor, then loop through the cursor to process each row.  Currently I'm getting the error "ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception", and I'm out of ideas.  Can anyone provide some insight?

```
DECLARE
  cursor photos is select PHOTO_ID from placer_photo;
  v_file_content blob;
  v_file_display blob;
  v_thumb blob;
  v_id number;

BEGIN
for i in photos
loop
  SELECT photo_id, file_content, file_display, file_thumbnail INTO v_id, v_file_content, v_file_display, v_thumb FROM placer_photo where photo_id = i.photo_id
  for update;

  /*DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_id);*/

  ordimage.processCopy(v_file_content, 'maxScale=800 800', v_file_display);
  ordimage.processCopy(v_file_content, 'maxScale=32 32', v_thumb);

  UPDATE placer_photo
  SET file_thumbnail = v_thumb,
  file_display = v_file_display
  where photo_id = i.photo_id;
  COMMIT;
end loop;
END;
```

EDIT: Got it to work.

```
DECLARE
  cursor photos is select * from placer_photo where photo_id = 118 for update;
  v_file_content blob;
  v_file_display blob;
  v_thumb blob;
  v_id number;
  v_date date;

BEGIN
for i in photos
loop

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.photo_id);

  v_file_content := i.file_content;
  v_file_display := i.file_display;
  v_thumb := i.file_thumbnail;

  ordimage.processCopy(v_file_content, 'maxScale=800 800', v_file_display);
  ordimage.processCopy(v_file_content, 'maxScale=100 100', v_thumb);

  update placer_photo
  set file_display = v_file_display,
  file_thumbnail = v_thumb
  where current of photos;

end loop;
END;
```

Comment: What version database are you using? This functionality is being phased out.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.  Had to change some things up.

```
  cursor photos is select * from placer_photo for update;
  v_file_content blob;
  v_file_display blob;
  v_thumb blob;
  v_id number;
  v_date date;

BEGIN
for i in photos
loop

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.photo_id);

  v_file_content := i.file_content;
  v_file_display := i.file_display;
  v_thumb := i.file_thumbnail;

  ordimage.processCopy(v_file_content, 'maxScale=800 800', v_file_display);
  ordimage.processCopy(v_file_content, 'maxScale=100 100', v_thumb);

  update placer_photo
  set file_display = v_file_display,
  file_thumbnail = v_thumb
  where current of photos;

end loop;
END;
```